# Applet fails to draw compoents properly after refreshing page in browser

Tags: java, applet

When I wait until java tray icon is gone, everything loads properly!

Java Version: SE 6 Update 22

```
public void init()
{

    try
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                initComponents();
                invalidate();
                doLayout();


            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this 'your applet' or 'all applets' that the problem occurs in?  If applet components were added during the start() method, it could result in the behavior you describe.  BTW - Please remove the 'chrome' tag.

Comment: I removed Chrome tag. Look at my  init().

Answer (score 0):

If your having problems with Chrome, it is better to file a bug:

http://crbug.com/new

Loading / refreshing applets work fine in [Chrome 10](https://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)+

Comment: Sorry! It wasn't only in Chrome. it's in all browsers! Any idea?